# jQuery dúvida append appendTo injetar HTML

Tags: jquery, html, append

Olá,

Estou com uma dúvida.

Tenho uma variável contendo uma estrutura html e preciso injetar uma div básica (< div > < / div >) em volta de todo o conteúdo dessa variável, como um pai, usando somente jQuery.

Acredito que devo utilizar o append e appendTo, mas estou perdida.

Alguma dica? Obrigada

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nesse caso podes usar o [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) assim:

```
$(".o-teu-conteudo-existente").wrap("<div class='nova-div'></div>");
```

Dessa maneira o jQuery muda o conteúdo para dentro dessa nova `div`.

Comment: Eu vim aqui pra responder com `.append`, mas sua solução é muito melhor! +1

Comment: Era EXATAMENTE isso, obrigada !!